# How do you force express on node.js in Azure Websites to use https?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, express, azure-web-app-service

Running on Windows Azure Websites, I want to use ssl via the default *.azurewebsites.net certificate.  It works without doing anything, but http is also available for every destination, not just https.  How do I force a redirect from http to https?  Normally I could just do something like:

```
var https = require('https');

...

var options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('path.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('path.crt')
    };

...

https.createServer(options, app)
```

but since I don't know anything about the *.azurewebsites.net certificate, such as its path, that's not going to work.

How do I redirect all or some requests to https?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `web.config`, add the following rule before any other rule that has `stopProcessing="true"`.

```
<rule name="RedirecttoHTTPS">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="/$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

You can also just use the normal `http.createServer(app)` for production if you want to the *.azurewebsite.net wildcard certificate.

References:

1. [How to require SSL in IIS7 and Azure with Rewrite](http://www.pettijohn.com/2011/07/how-to-require-ssl-in-iis7-and-azure.html)
2. [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

Comment: This is working, but opens the app.js file on browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me, it would just display a blank page, this one:

```
<!-- Redirect all traffic to SSL -->
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

From https://gist.github.com/tstpierre/afec7eb409aebe0bf3d1 works perfectly though.

Comment: This works, but it opens my app.js file on the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to validate that your node app is receiving secure traffic from within the node app, Richard Astbury has a [solution on his blog](https://coderead.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/redirecting-to-https-in-node-js-on-azure-websites/).

**tl;dr**: IIS is acting as a proxy to the node app, and adds an "x-arr-ssl" header to requests if they were served over HTTPS. You can also use the "x-site-deployment-id" header to validate whether or not your app is currently running in azure. The middleware ends up like so:

```
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    var isAzure = req.get('x-site-deployment-id'),
        isSsl = req.get('x-arr-ssl');

    if (isAzure && !isSsl) {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
    }

    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

While you're at it, it's a good idea to add HSTS, too:

```
var helmet = require('helmet');

function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    var isAzure = req.get('x-site-deployment-id'),
        isSsl = req.get('x-arr-ssl');

    if (isAzure && !isSsl) {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
    }

    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
app.use(helmet.hsts({
    maxAge: 10886400000,     // Must be at least 18 weeks to be approved by Google
    includeSubdomains: true, // Must be enabled to be approved by Google
    preload: true
}));
```

Of course you can always do this in tandem with the web.config answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like Azure Websites is acting as a reverse proxy in your case, this approch may work for you:

If you can get the protocol from the following, it should help you:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']
```

This should give you the http or https you need to key on on order to do a redirect if it is not valid for the resource you are serving.

I use code like the following to redirect any time I get a request (for an html file or site root for example). I put all the files I want to be secure in a /secure directory to make it easy to know what should and should not be ssl:

```
protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];

if ((req.url.lastIndexOf('.html') == (req.url.length - 5)) || (req.url.slice(-1) == '/')) {
    if (protocol == 'http') {

        if (req.url.indexOf('/secure/') == 0) {
            console.log('Non ssl request made to secure resource: ' + req.url);
            console.log('Redirecting to https://' + site_host_name + req.url);
            res.writeHead(301,
                {Location: 'https://' + site_host_name + req.url}
            );
            res.end();
            return;
        } else {
            next();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if (req.url.indexOf('/secure/') != 0) {
            console.log('ssl request made for non-secure resource: ' + req.url);
            console.log('Redirecting to http://' + site_host_name + req.url);
            res.writeHead(301,
                {Location: 'http://' + site_host_name + req.url}
            );
            res.end();
            return;
        } else {
            next();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```