# Redirect rule on azure redirects the browser to app.js file

Tags: node.js, azure

I was trying to enforce https on azure for my app running on node server which has an angular front-end. The redirection works(it goes to https instead of http) but it shows my app.js file(https:// hostname.com/app.js) on browser instead of serving the angular index.js file.
My web.config looks like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
        
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule> 
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have already tried the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578283/how-do-you-force-express-on-node-js-in-azure-websites-to-use-https/%22here%22)

Comment: I am really having issue understanding the need of your "DynamicContent" rule. But I do believe that it is causing your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21010038/1989391) answer. Although, it did not work when added the redirection rule as it is mentioned in the answer but I do noticed the same problem which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33565283/1989391), a blank page. The reason for that was I was getting a CORS error when the redirection from http to https was happening. This is the final version of web.config which worked for me

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket 

support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirecttoHTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
 <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, Authorization, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, X-Olaround-Request-Start-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-End-Timestamp, X-Olaround-

Request-Time, X-Olaround-Request-Method, X-Olaround-Request-Result, X-Olaround-Request-Endpoint" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I added this to get rid of the CORS error:

```html
    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, Authorization, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, X-Olaround-Request-Start-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-End-Timestamp, X-Olaround-Request-Time, X-Olaround-Request-Method, X-Olaround-Request-Result, X-Olaround-Request-Endpoint" />    
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to simply change the order of the rules. I placed the rule that rewrites to HTTP as the first and it worked.

```
            <rule name="Redirect to https">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" ignoreCase="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
```