# node.js with ssl and static files serving

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I have a problem which I can't manage to set a node js server that support ssl and also can serve static files over this ssl, when I am adding the **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))** the files are being serve from https regular server.
some one has tried to do that?

```
//require engines
var express     = require('express');
var session     = require('express-session');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser')

//init express engine
var app = express();

//using
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var activeport = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 4003;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

    var fs = require('fs');
    var https = require('https');

    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(global.appRoot + '/xxx.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(global.appRoot + '/yyy.crt'),
        passphrase: "123123",
        requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    };

    var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(activeport, function () {
        console.log('Server listening on port ' + activeport);
    });
}
else {
    app.listen(activeport, function () {
        console.log('Server listening on port ' + activeport);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are in production mode? Seems like you might actually be in the else block

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const path = require('path'); // <--- Require this
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Got it.
Becouse i am using Azure as my hosting provider, Azure is taken care all of the SSL support for you, so i didn't needed to create a dedicated **https** server:

```
var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(activeport, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + activeport);
});
```

All i needed to do is to add my web.config the following code - a permanent redirect to the https url.

```
<!-- Redirect all traffic to SSL -->
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Referar:
[How do you force express on node.js in Azure Websites to use https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578283/how-do-you-force-express-on-node-js-in-azure-websites-to-use-https)